# ETPush.registerForNotifications() method in JB4A SDK Cordova Plugin, callback not working

Tags: javascript, journeybuilder, mobilepush-android, cordova

I've created a Github issue for this as well, find it here: https://github.com/ExactTarget/JB4A-SDK-CordovaPlugin/issues/3. The Github issue has images and code to review.

For a quick summary, the plugin provides a way to receive the data from a push notification, but is currently not working as expected. Instead of my callback getting called when I tap a push notification, a random javascript function is called on the window object, which goes nowhere. All other work with the plugin has been great, but **I cannot figure out why or how to receive the push notification data in my app using the Journey Builder SDK** for Mobile Push apps. Please advise.

Comment: Plugin was broken, but I've submitted a pull request. Use my repo if they don't accept my PR, and you'll have successful notification data delivered to your javascript.